# Averaging the duplicate tuples from list of tuples based on their values

Tags: python, list, average, mean

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
lst:
    [(1, 1, 18), (1, 1, 19), (1, 2, 7), (1, 2, 8), (1, 3, 31), (1, 4, 11), (1, 4, 15),(1, 5, 3)]
```

I want to get the average of the tuples which their two first items are similar. So from the above example, my desired output would be:

```
out_lst:
    [(1, 1, 18.5), (1, 2, 7.5), (1, 3, 31), (1, 4, 13), (1,5,3)]
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? How would you solve the problem with paper and pencil? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coul try something like this, this is not very efficicent but it will do the trick

```py
input_list = [(1, 1, 18), (1, 1, 19), (1, 2, 7), (1, 2, 8), (1, 3, 31), (1, 4, 11), (1, 4, 15),(1, 5, 3)]

compute_dic = {}
for elem in input_list:
    compute_dic.setdefault((elem[0], elem[1]), []).append(elem[2])

out = [(k[0], k[1], sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in compute_dic.items()]

print(out)
```

Comment: You can use `compute_dic.setdefault((elem[0], elem[1]), []).append(elem[2])` instead of 5 lines inside the for

Answer (score 2):

You can use itertools.groupby and statistics.mean

```
import itertools
import statistics
keyfunc = lambda kk: (kk[0],kk[1])
by_two = itertools.groupby( sorted( lst, key= keyfunc ) , key= keyfunc )
our_lst = [ ( kk[0], kk[1], statistics.mean( map(lambda tp: tp[2], vv) ) ) for kk,vv in by_two ]

print(our_lst)
# print [(1, 1, 18.5), (1, 2, 7.5), (1, 3, 31), (1, 4, 13), (1, 5, 3)]
```